# How do I register a stylesheet inside a WordPress widget?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, widget

I'm developing a WordPress widget following [Dave Clements tutorial](http://www.doitwithwp.com/how-to-create-wordpress-widget-step-by-step/). It works well. Now I want to add some styles to it. I want the styles to be in an extra css file which will be loaded during runtime. I'm calling this function

```
function myprefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
  wp_register_style( 'myprefix-style', plugins_url('mystyle.css', __FILE__) );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'myprefix-style' );
}
```

right before "// Widget output //" using this statement.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_add_my_stylesheet' );
```

But nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try asking the question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, bretterer, done so and [got an answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56710/how-do-i-register-a-stylesheet-inside-a-wordpress-widget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **wp_enqueue_scripts** action do not work because you call it too late, in **widget()** function (widget output). It's too late because Wordpress already print/send head of page.
For example, you can add this action on widget construct function.

Comment: Thanks! Got a slightly different but also correct answer at [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56718).